# How to solve error parsing in dataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a function button that carry user info `fullname`, after clicking the button, it will send `fullname` and `level` to an API to be process and the result should be display in dataTable. Unfortunately, I got this error.

[image]

This is console.log for `console.log(params)`. `{"task_level":3,"fullname":"Administrator"}`

Below is console.log for `console.log(params)`.

[image]

Both console log is similar to API's result.

I don't know which is proper.

**JS 1st Try** (1st Ajax to send the parameter to API and after return success hopefully working but not.

```
"<button type='button' class='btn btn-dark btn-round' onclick='viewTablePerson(&quot;"+value.fullname+"&quot;)'>View Project</button>"+

function viewTablePerson(fullname){

    var level = 3;
    var fullname2 = fullname;

    var obj = {
        task_level : level,
        fullname   : fullname2        
    };

    var params = JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(params)

    $.ajax({
        url : url_api + '/api/user_task',
        crossDomain: true,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: params,
        success: function(response){
            if (response.status == "Success"){
            console.log(response)
                $('#viewProgress').DataTable({
                    ajax: { 
                        url: url_api + '/api/user_task',
                        crossDomain : true,
                        type : "POST",
                        cache : false,
                        dataType : "json",
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: true,
                        data : params,
                        timeout: 10000,
                    },
                    destroy: true,        
                    columns: [
                        { data : "task_name"},
                        { data : "task_owner"},
                        { data : "task_status"}
                    ],
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(e){}
    });
}
```

JS 2nd Try

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-dark btn-round' onclick='viewTablePerson(&quot;"+value.fullname+"&quot;)'>View Project</button>"+

function viewTablePerson(fullname){

    var level = 3;
    var fullname2 = fullname;

    var obj = {
        task_level : level,
        fullname   : fullname2
    };

    var params = JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(params)

    $('#viewProgress').DataTable({
        ajax: { 
            url: url_api + '/api/user_task',
            crossDomain : true,
            type : "POST",
            cache : false,
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: false,
            processData: true,
            data : params,
            timeout: 10000,
        },
        destroy: true,
        columns: [
            { data : "task_name"},
            { data : "task_owner"},
            { data : "task_status"}
        ],
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7) says:

> When using the ajax option to load data for DataTables, a general error can be triggered if the server responds with anything other than a valid HTTP 2xx response.

So, you have to check server-side response instead of search for problems on the front-end.
Also, in your case make sure

- the plugin sends request to the same domain from which the current page is loaded;
- browser security system doesn't prevent loading of external scripts - for example on *http://localhost* you cannot Ajax load a script from *http://google.com* without special measures;
- you are specifying a relative path without a domain name (if you are using a single domain);
- JSON data in response is a valid.

If you cannot alter the backend system to fix the error, but don't want your end users to see the alert message, you can change DataTables' error reporting mechanism to throw a Javascript error to the browser's console, rather than alerting it:

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
```